# Collision detection Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

```
var kursor:Kursor = new Kursor(); 
var kulki:Array = new Array();

var i:int = 0;
for(;i<40;i++){
    var kula:Kula = new Kula();
    kulki.push(kula);
}

function sprawdzKolizje(event:Event){

if(kursor.hitTestObject(linia)){
   trace("wykrylem");
   }
}`
```

When i detect collision normal MC : kursor with linia is ok, detected. When I detect MC in Array with linia no detected.

```
kursor.hitTestObject(linia) - OK
kulki.hitTestObject(linia) - BAD
kula.hitTestObject(linia) - BAD
kulki[0].hitTestObject(linia) - BAD
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

1. `kulki.hitTestObject(linia)` won't work because `hitTestObject` is a method of `DisplayObject` not `Array`.
2. Make sure all objects have been added to the display list.

Answer (score 0):

```
   kursor.hitTestObject(linia) - OK
```

Would indicate that kursor & linia have been properly instantiated and added to the display list. From that you can deduct that your "kula" objects may be the cause of the problem.

```
   for(var i:int; i<40 ; i++)
   {
        var kula:Kula = new Kula();
        kulki.push(kula);
   }
```

may also work better...

Finally, checking your objects may give you an indication of what goes wrong.

```
   trace( kula );
   kula.hitTestObject(linia);

   trace( kulki );
   trace( kulki[0] );
   kulki[0].hitTestObject(linia) - BAD
```